# How to convert unicode text to normal text

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ascii

I am learning Beautiful Soup in Python.

I am trying to parse a simple webpage with list of books.

E.g

```
<a href="https://www.nostarch.com/carhacking">The Car Hacker’s Handbook</a>
```

I use the below code.

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('http://nostarch.com')
res.raise_for_status()
nSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
elems = nSoup.select('.product-body a')

#elems[0] gives
<a href="https://www.nostarch.com/carhacking">The Car Hacker\u2019s Handbook</a>
```

And

```
#elems[0].getText() gives
u'The Car Hacker\u2019s Handbook'
```

But I want the proper text which is given by,

```
s = elems[0].getText()
print s
>>>The Car Hacker’s Handbook
```

How to modify my code in order to give "The Car Hacker’s Handbook" output instead of "u'The Car Hacker\u2019s Handbook'"  ?

Kindly help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the result you are getting. It is a unicode string with a fancy apostrophe character.

Comment: Thanks, @Selcuk .
But how to use that string "u'The Car Hacker\u2019s Handbook' " and store in file/database?

Will it be properly stored ? I mean I tried `f.write(elems[0].getText())`, I got UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: Thanks , @Selcuk . I got it.

I used `elems[0].getText().encode('utf-8')` to save into file or database.

Comment: If you want to store unicode text in a database then set up the column to be of a text type and set up the database adapter to handle the de- and encoding for you. The `io` module contains text file types which convert between unicode and bytes while writing and reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the encode method?

```
elems[0].getText().encode('utf-8')
```

More info about unicode and python can be found in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Moreover, to discover if your string is really utf-8 encoded you can use [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) and run the following command:

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(elems[0].getText()) 
{'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

Comment: THANKS.
I tried `elems[0].getText().encode('utf-8')`. It worked.

Python terminal prints it as `'The Car Hacker\xe2\x80\x99s Handbook'` but if written to a file, the file contents has `The Car Hacker’s Handbook` in it.

Comment: Cool. I edited the answer just for the sake of correctness.

Comment: @madhusudan_k Welcome to SO. If you think you resolve what you were looking for by this answer, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the arrow just below the voting count.

Comment: @madhusudan_k python doesn't have utf-8 encoding so that's why you are getting unicode instead (on python console)

Comment: Calling `chardet.detect()` with a unicode string doesn't make sense. It's for detecting encodings in byte strings.

Answer (score -2):

you can try

```
import unicodedata

def normText(unicodeText):
return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodeText).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

This will convert unicodetext to plain text and you can write to a file.

Comment: It also removes the ”apostrophe” so the book title becomes „The Car Hackers Handbook“.